# OFBiz multi-tenancy

Tags: database, multi-tenant, ofbiz, opentaps

Can different parts of the the OFBiz/Opentaps application connect to different tenants in a multi-tenancy configuration?

Example:

- Party Management => connect to default database
- Catalog Management => connect to tenant1

Working in the same instance of Ofbiz application

Answer (score 0):

OFBiz multi tenancy works by using separate database for each tenant.
And ofbiz application has database level interdependencies, so all the applications have to be in the same database. So the answer is NO, you cannot have individual OFBiz applications in separate databases.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Bilgin. Another question related to this - when i enable multi-tenance in framework/common/config/general.properties, by changing the multitenant option to Y, how can i still access the original ofbiz database (not tenant) without manually having to disable the multi-tenancy option to N in the general.properties file? When you enable multi-tenancy and restart ofbiz, it will automatically bring up the logon screen for the tenant. How can i choose between the database from the UI and not manually in the general.properties file?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/multitenancy-support.html

Hi Bilgin. Given the link above, if you read the section "Setting the ecommerce app. to use a specific Tenant Database" close to the bottom of the page, it seems to me like this would allow you to connect different parts of the ofbiz application (party management, catalog management etc)to different databases. Can you please then explain to me your understanding of this section? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no problem in connecting tenant databases to each component like `Catalog Manager` or `Party Manager`.This can be done through changing the `web.xml` file of each component.But as you know, `OFBiz` is tightly coupled,so it may affect the flow of your application because components like order manager,facility manager and accounting have data level dependencies.